# Android animate visibility change for two views at once

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to hide two views (a `Viewpager` and a `LinearLayout`) at once when a `Button` is clicked. I tried using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`, but it will always start hiding the `Viewpager` first and then the `LinearLayout`, which doesn't look good.

How can I manually hide both views at the same time? I have seen examples like this were the visibility of one view is changed:

```
myImageView.animate()
        .translationY(myImageView.getHeight())
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(300)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
```

Is there a way to chain two animate() calls of different `Views`to trigger them simultaneously?

EDIT: This is my layout file, the `Views` I want to hide at the same time are the `Viewpager`with the id viewpager and the `LinearLayout` with the id ll_indicators:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tv_statusbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_statusbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/statusbar_height" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/some_text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontSizeMedium"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_indicators"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/intro_indicator_0"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/intro_indicator_1"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_unselected" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/ll_login"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        layout="@layout/item_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </include>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't post your layout, if you can put your ViewPager and LinearLayout in one layout, (for example inside a RelativeLayout) then you can animate that.

Comment: I have updated my question, the ViewPager and the LinearLayout are part of the same layout.

Comment: Well, then put them inside a <FrameLayout>  and animate that. Let me know if you want me to post the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( A.isShowing && B.isSowing(
A.hide
b.hide
)
```

Maybe this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either just animate the parent LinearLayout, all Views within will animate with it :

```
yourLinearLayout.animate().setDuration(300).alpha(0).   ...
```

, or call animate() on two Views simultaneously :

```
  yourImageView.animate().alpha(0).    ...
  yourLinearLayout.animate().alpha(0).    ...
```

which would look like they are disappearing at the same time.